# JavaScript if() statement or/and operators

Tags: javascript

Can I ask for validation of my statement if is ok and can be refactor?

Condition:

fire if **A** or **B** or **C** are not blank 
and **D or and E or and F or and G** are blank"

```
 if((A !== '' || B !== '' || C !== '') && (D === "" || E === ''
   || F === '' || G === '')){

      console.log("fire")
   }
```

Comment: Looks correct to me :)

Comment: Looks confusing to me. What should "**D or and E**" be?

Comment: Well except that "or and" should be just "or" in the text description, yes it's fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code review questions should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @adiga in fairness, I'm not sure if the question is suitable to CR - it's much too short. I saw a similarly short question looking for best practices and it was closed for lack of context.

Answer (score 1):

You could take just the values of the **string** variables, like

> ```
> s !== '' is equal to  s
> s === '' is equal to !s
> ```

```
if ((A || B || C) && (!D || !E || !F || !G)) {
```

Comment: what if A,B,C etc, are 0, or `false`. 0 is not blank but will fail all the time.

Comment: i assume, as i wrote, that the variables contains strings.

Comment: Just for fun I plugged that boolean equation to [this website to see if it can be simplified](https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator) and I got `(a && !d) || (a && !e) || (a && !f) || (a && !g) || (b && !d) || (b && !e) || (b && !f) || (b && !g) || (c && !d) || (c && !e) || (c && !f) || (c && !g)` which doesn't seem simpler.

Comment: `&& !(D && E && F && G)`